# Brown leaves on antherium in water

Tags: diagnosis

My antherium is developing brown patches on the leaves.

The plant was transferred from soil to water approximately 4 months ago. Filtered water is changed every 2 weeks & soaked plant in very low dose of fertilizer in water overnight approx 2 months ago, washed roots in morning & back into filtered water.

Can you help with a likely cause please.

[image: Antherium leaves with brown discolouration from the tips]

Comment: Why would you try growing anthuriums in water?

Comment: Not a helpful comment thanks. If this is an indication of this group, don't think I'll bother to post again!

Comment: Dear Meredy, I agree with the above comment. Its intent seems to be the same as any good comment under a question - to direct the asking person to write a better question. I beg You to realize this is not an evil criticism but rather a random guy donating their time for Your question to be better answered. Cheers!